# Create a sidebar in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to create a sidebar like following (screenshot from IntelliJ IDEA) in Vaadin.

[image]

I googled for a way but may be my search terms are not that good I couldn't find much about creating something like this.

I am going to create this using some buttons placed in a vertical layout where each button shows/hides another layout which contains the widget for each button.

Is this a suitable approach? Are there any better ways to do this?

Also, how can I make the button text vertical, if I were going to implement this in described approach?

Comment: The sidepanel addon will probably do most of what you wish. https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/sidepanel Bet the vertical text is not something existing in html...

Comment: you can try to transform/rotate the text via css.  not sure, how that would work with the addon or with vaadin calculating sizes, though.